# Accion de usuario activo o inactivo JSP pagina web

Tags: html, jsp

Alguien me ayuda con este codigo, quisiera realizar una accion en mi tabla mediante un button, que me edite la tabla de TRUE A FALSE o viceversa para dar entender si usuario esta activo o no pero no me funciona.

```
 if ( request.getParameter("p_cambio")!=null ) {
   //CAMBIAR VIGENCIA 
try {
            Dba db = new Dba(application.getRealPath("")+"/daw.mdb");
            db.conectar(); 
            int contador=db.query.executeUpdate("UPDATE empleados "
                    + "SET e_estado='"+request.getParameter("e_estado")+"'"
                    + "WHERE id='"+ request.getParameter("ti_id")+"' ");

              if(contador>=1){
                
                  
            }
            db.commit();
            db.desconectar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    %>
```

como seria la accion en el button.